# Dell PowerEdge r720 - Retrieve system messages from OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2, dell-poweredge

Is it possible at all?

i am currently playing around with the new server and seen the nice blue light in front,
connecting only one power supply created an alarming orange light with a message about the 2nd psu not connected.
is there a way i can send those messages to myself?

still havent decided on the os (was recommended to install ubuntu server, but im more an ms guy and i would prefer to install win 2008 r2).

Comment: DOMSA and DOME - http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1760.openmanage-server-administrator-omsa.aspx - http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1989.openmanage-essentials.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to install the Dell OpenManage Server Administrator agents for your preferred operating system in order to provide alerting of system events and hardware health.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to look into iDRAC if you have this hardware module come with your server hardware. There is email alert sending feature built-in.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it:

- The R720 has built in iDRAC6 express, and optional upgrade to iDRAC6 enterprise.  Both allow you to manage the server - reboot remotely, view hardware issues, etc.  This needs to be enabled first.  The manual for the server will walk you through it.  Once setup, there will be an HTTPS server on a different IP address you can login to even if the server is powered off.
- Install the openmanage software from Dell.  This allows you to view all the hardware issues from a web browser - the web server runs inside the OS.
- If you don't like logging in to check it out, the iDRAC can be configured to send email alerts.
- The iDRAC and openmanage can both be read through SNMP - so a monitoring system can read  the status of all the hardware.

I find the iDRAC to be a better place to check for alerts than the openmanage software (though still install the openmanage software), because I can still check on it even if the server isn't bootable or the OS has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed `iDRAC7` remote access controller in your Dell `R720` server, I would continue with installation of Dell `OpenManage Server Administrator` (or `OMSA`).

The OMSA is a software agent that provides system management interface either from an easy web browser based interface or from a command line interface through the operating system.
These tools are  available for sysadmins who can manage servers both locally and remotely on a network. Additionally, the OMSA agent can be connected  to the  centralized management Dell `OpenManage Essentials` (or `OME`) console.

The OMSA packages are available for both Windows and Linux platforms. I'm more familiar with Linux deployements so I would recommend you to visit Dell wiki and the  [repository/OMSA](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/hardware) page. There is introduced how to install the OMSA packages on the most of Linux distros. More generic information, including how to install OMSA on Windows , can be found in the [system management](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1760.openmanage-server-administrator-omsa.aspx) wiki page.

Once you are done with OMSA, you can use `racadm` command to access `iDRAC` procesor either remotely:

> racadm -r iDRAC_IP_ADDR -u iDRAC_USER -p iDRAC_USER_PASS SUBCOMMAND

Or locally:

> racadm SUBCOMMAND

Where `SUBCOMMAND` for retrieving system event log (hardware log) is:

> getsel

The complete list of all supported `SUBCOMMANDs` can be found on [this page](http://goo.gl/Wy3BmY).